# How can I make two apps communicate (sending data from one app to another)

Tags: android-studio, communication

I've made an app that currently sends an email with the information that you enter into the app

My app is for teachers who sends the email to one specific teacher. But I'd like to design another app that would receive the information instead of being sent by email.

**Explanation:**

We'll call them app **A** and app **B**

In app **A** the user writes in the information and when they're done they click send. That information should then be received by app **B** and be displayed

Answer (score 0):

Here you need a online server with some backend work.

Comment: Excuse my lack of knowledge. But currently for my app I'm using Firebase for user login. Is it possible Firebase has something I can use for this????

Comment: Yes you can use Firebase Real Time Database to store the messages and also to retrieve the message to the second app i.e  Send the message from app A and the store it to Firebase Database and then get the same message from the Firebase Database to your second app i.e app B.